# after upgrade Archiva to 2.1.1 version from 1.3 doesn't work admin password

Tags: maven, passwords, admin, upgrade, archiva

No more works password for admin. In archiva.xml admin is in default users.
And not propose on start page to set admin password.
Already tried deleted users dir. Problems persists.
Any ideas please?

Answer (score 0):

From my personal experience, I've had success by resetting the Admin password 6 times (the default amount of previous passwords stored by Archiva) to retain the same password.  Make sure that the admin's email address is set to an email address belonging to an account that you can access.

You could reset your password 1 time of course, but that might entail you having to change your password in multiple places, such as your Maven settings.xml, Jenkins, etc.